# What is the definition of a 街開き?

Tags: translation, words

What is a 街開き? I know that 街 can mean "town" and 開き means "opening", so it means something like "town opening", but what is it exactly?

Neither jisho.org nor weblio had an entry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

街開き is not very common, but it's actually *town opening*. It's used when a newly developed town (or district, or large apartment building) is made available to the public use. It also refers to an opening ceremony.

See:

- [「開成町みなみ」街開き式](http://kanagawa.itot.jp/kaisei/231)
- [変わる東京。今後注目したい新しい「街開き」](https://www.athome.co.jp/contents/trend/071/)
- [分譲住宅地でなぜ「街びらき」イベントが行われたのか](https://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/455869/)

---

**EDIT** While 街開き is not common, it's instantly understandable to native speakers because we have similar ～開き words:

- [海開き](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%B5%B7%E9%96%8B%E3%81%8D)
- [プール開き](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%97%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E9%96%8B%E3%81%8D)
- [山開き](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%B1%B1%E9%96%8B%E3%81%8D)